# Gradle build fails saying : Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm:0.3.3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building a new project using Android Studio Canary and while setting up dependencies for jet pack compose I get this as build output:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm:0.3.3.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.0.0-beta02
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SzRA.png)

Answer (score 9):

Add jcenter to the repositories of your settings.gradle file.
You can specify that it should only be used for this missing artefact.
It should look like this:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    //noinspection JcenterRepositoryObsolete
    jcenter {
        content {
            includeModule("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding jcenter() to your repositories. It's being phased out and you'll get a warning, but at the moment it is the only solution. See this:
https://github.com/ReKotlin/ReKotlin/issues/47

and https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/  : "To clarify, the JCenter repository will keep serving packages for 12 months until February 1st 2022. Only the JCenter REST API and UI will be sunsetted on May 1st 2021."

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this thread](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable/issues/96), I get rid of jcenter from my Jetpack Compose project by:

1. Modify the dependencies.kt in BuildSrc to add

```kotlin
object Collections {
    private const val version = "0.3.4"
    const val immutable = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm:$version"
}
```

2. Modify the build.gradle(Module:) to add

```kotlin
implementation Libs.Collections.immutable
```

3. Replace jcenter with mavenCentral from

- build.gradle(Porject:)
- build.gradle(Module:)
- build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could add explicitly to force the dependency resolution.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm:0.3.4"
```

Go to this link for more info https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable/issues/96#issuecomment-812994820

Answer (score 0):

I had a spell error and caused the wrong like this, check if you had a spell error.
For my case ,I spelled 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android' to 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutinesandroid' and caused the build error